# How do I include shared-library dependencies with my binary (w/o using a .deb or .rpm), and/or statically link against PulseAudio?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, pulseaudio

I'm having hard times in building a command line tools, written in C++, so that it could be executed by both i386 and amd64 versions of Ubuntu (ideally other distros as well, but that's not so important). It will be distributed on an USB key, so I have no control about packaging.

My command line tool should play some audio from a buffer as well, and so I'm using PulseAudio Simple in order to play audio buffers.

Please note that my executable runs fine on my development machine. Problems arises when I copy it on a USB key and run it on other machines. There, as soon as I launch my executable, i get a "File not found" error from bash; from what I have learned, it should be because of missing libpulse-dev package (and so the library, which is dynamically linked) on the target machine.

So, I'm kindly asking: what I'm supposed to do? I tried to build a 32bit static PulseAudio but then I can't even get it to compile, and honestly I don't know what else to try. Is there another way, apart from static linking, to deploy shared libraries with my application in a USB key?

Thanks

Comment: Try harder to make a static binary, or at least to link every library outside of `libc` statically. BTW, it might be simpler to install a 32 bits distribution in a `chroot`-ed environmnent using `debootstrap`

Comment: Can you show your IDE setup/build command? Is it really a 32-bit package? Is it linked against correct libraries?

Comment: Sounds like you've got 3 questions here: (1) how do I build a 32-bit binary on amd64? (2) How do I include shared-library dependencies with my binary (w/o using a .deb or .rpm)? or (3) How do I statically link with pulse audio? I suggest asking separate questions for each of these...

Comment: So you know how to do (1); this means that your title is misleading (you already know how to do that part).

Comment: I added -m32 to both linker and compiler options (I'm using CodeLite, by the way) and by typing in bash:
`file <myexec>`
I get
`ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=..., not stripped`
so I guess that the executable is 32bit. Also, I have installed libpulse-dev:i386 on my machine, and by launching file on libpulse.so
i also get
`ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=...`

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, thanks for the input, question title edited

Comment: 1. Include all relevant shared libraries on the stick, run `ldd your_app` to check which one are relevant
2. Make POSIX shell script to run your app
3. In the script point to your libraries by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriatly

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux thanks for your suggestion. I wonder why you did use a comment rather than an answer to submit it; I'd gladly accept it as a solution since it seems it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please include all relevant shared libraries on the stick. To do that, run `ldd your_app` to get list of relevant libraries.
2. Make preferable POSIX shell script to invoke your application
3. In the script point to your libraries by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriatly

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, and it's Working fine. Thanks.